# Remove characters from a string after a certain word - excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, text-processing, strip

Ive got a list of imported data that is formatted as the following in a excel / google spreadsheet. In column A i have the full data and in B im trying to strip out the data to the left of the word `ON`.

```
FULL DATA                      |      STRIPPED DATA


NNK GOV ON 31 AUG CDE          |      NNK GOV 
GIFFGAFF.COM ON 30 AUG CDE     |      GIFFGAFF.COM
TMRCO STORES  ON 12 AUG   CDE  |      TMRCO STORES
```

I was using the following forumal, but it falls down where there is non uniform white space as there is on the last entry.

`=LEFT(a1, LEN(a1)-14)`

Is there a more robust way i can write this, so it dosnt fall over when there is non uniform whitespace or additional wording after "CDE" ?

Ive created a shared google spreadsheet here as a scratch pad : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iieR_hAk8qJpy8W6Qq7ww9-640o-HZMFLNNjecps6m4/edit#gid=0

Im using google spreadsheets, although ive marked this question as excel also as ive found there to be many shared functions.

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In excel:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ON",A1)))
```

This will work in Google sheets also but there may be an easier way in google sheets that uses Regex.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"(.*) ON .*")
```

I also added it on your sheet in the stripped column.

If you want to check if the condition exists, otherwise it might return an error:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"(.*) ON .*")),REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"(.*) ON .*"), A3 )
```